# WordPress echo post meta array value inside input

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress

I'm sending array meta box data using update_post_meta like below. However I cannot seem to output the post meta array value into an empty input. The meta is being stored correctly.

```
if( get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'date-meta', true ) ) {
    $date_info = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'date-meta', true );
}
```

My input field looks like this:

```
<input type="date" class="widefat" name="vp-date" id="vp-date" value="<?php echo $date_info['vp-date']; ?>" />
```

I also get a notice which traces back to the if get_post_meta function above. It says:

```
Trying to get property of non-object in
```

Any help would be great.

Thanks

Comment: Can you update your question to include more code giving us context? The answer to this depends on where you're using the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That error message means that the $post is $post->ID is not an object. I don't know what script you are in but try putting

`global $post;`

above the if.

Making it

```
global $post;
if( get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'date-meta', true ) ) {
    $date_info = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'date-meta', true );
}
```

Comment: Thanks - any security issues with using global $post inside a plugin?

Comment: None - you are only accessing a variable that is in the global scope - anything insecure shouldn't be accessible in such a way :-) - it is the way Wordpress runs. It does have limitations in when it is instatiated (facepalm) but I haven't found them yet :-).